# Time Complexity and Space Complexity of the Python Code

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity, code-complexity

Can someone please help me with the time and space complexity of this code snippet? Please refer to the leetcode question- Word break ii.Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list of non-empty words, add spaces in s to construct a sentence where each word is a valid dictionary word. Return all such possible sentences.

```
def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
    dp = {}
    def word_break(s):
        if s in dp:
            return dp[s]
        result = []
        for w in wordDict:
            if s[:len(w)] == w:
                if len(w) == len(s):
                    result.append(w)
                else:
                    tmp = word_break(s[len(w):])
                    for t in tmp:
                        result.append(w + " " + t)
        dp[s] = result
        return result
    
    return word_break(s)
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Also, I'd suggest using different code formatting - it's hard to read when you use in-line `if` but multiline `else`.

Comment: I feel it's # of word*avg len of word * the entire string or n^2 where n is no of total characters in the string (including duplicates)

Comment: Ok, searching a substring in string using `in` operator is sublinear in the best-case and quadratic in the worst-case. Then iterating over keys of dictionary is O(n). Plus there are some comparisons and slicing, but it feels like overall the asymptotic complexity should be O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Decision Tree

[image]

### Time Complexity

- height of tree is `len(target)=m` in worst case
- branching is len(words)=n
- in each recursive call, you make slicing `if s[:len(w)]`. worst case is `m`
- T: O(N^m * M)=O(n^m)

### Space complexity

- space from call stack is the height of tree=m
- IN each recursive call you are making suffix and storing it. its length is m
- S : O(m*m)

Answer (score 0):

- For time complexity analysis, almost always we'd take the worst case scenario into account.
- I guess `O(N ^ 3)` runtime and `O(N)` memory would be right.
- Here is a breakdown:

```
def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
    dp = {}
    def word_break(s):
        # This block would be O(N) 
        if s in dp: # order of N
            return dp[s]
        result = []

        # This block would be O(N ^ 2)
        for w in wordDict: # order of N
            if s[:len(w)] == w:
                if len(w) == len(s):
                    result.append(w)
                else:
                    tmp = word_break(s[len(w):])
                    for t in tmp: # order of N
                        result.append(w + " " + t)
        dp[s] = result
        return result
    
    return word_break(s) # This'd be O(N) itself
```

- Therefore, `O(N ^ 2)` of the second block is multiplied by `O(N)` of calling the `word_break(s)` which would eventually make it `O(N ^ 3)`.
- We can a bit simplify it to:

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, words):
        dp = [False] * len(s)
        for i in range(len(s)): # order of N
            for word in words:  # order of N
                k = i - len(word)
                if word == s[k + 1:i + 1] and (dp[k] or k == -1):  # order of N
                    dp[i] = True
        return dp[-1]
```

which would make it easier to see:

- `for i in range(len(s)):` is an order of N;

  - `for word in words:` is an order of N;

    - `if word == s[k + 1:i + 1] and (dp[k] or k == -1):` is an order of N;

Comment: Shouldn't the second block be O(N)? Since it is only iterating through the string once- by iterating through the words and their individual characters.